# Unable to get Image details in the controller of Asp.net core

Tags: angular, typescript, asp.net-core

I want to store image details in the database but I am unable to get the image data in the controller which is sent from angular
I'm able to get the image information using the [FromForm] attribute in the controller parameter. But I want it inside the model. Thanks in Advance.

This is the Model in Asp.net core

```
public class FileModel
{
    public FileModel()
    {
        SpouseDetails = new SpouseDetailsData();
        ChildrensDetails = new List<ChildrensDetailsDataModel>();
    }
    public IFormFile? Photo { get; set; }
    //public byte[]? PhotoData { get; set; }
    public int UserDetailId { get; set; }
    public List<ChildrensDetailsDataModel>? ChildrensDetails { get; set; }
    public SpouseDetailsData SpouseDetails { get; set; }
    public class ChildrensDetailsDataModel
    {
        public string ChildCountry { get; set; } = null!;
        public string ChildCity { get; set; } = null!;
        public string ChildState { get; set; } = null!;
        public string ChildPhoneNumber { get; set; } = null!;
        public DateTime ChildDOB { get; set; }
        public string ChildLastName { get; set; }
        public string ChildEmailAddress { get; set; } = null!;
        public string ChildFirstName { get; set; } = null!;
    }
    public class SpouseDetailsData
    {
        public string SpouseEmail { get; set; } = null!;
        public string? SpouseCity { get; set; }
        public string? SpouseState { get; set; }
        public string? SpouseCountry { get; set; }
        public string SpouseHometown { get; set; } = null!;
        public string SpouseFirstName { get; set; } = null!;
        public string SpouseLastName { get; set; } = null!;
        public DateTime SpouseDob { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is the Angular code

```
   composeModel(): void {
    this.updateUserModel.firstName = this.profileForm.value.firstName;
    this.updateUserModel.lastName = this.profileForm.value.lastName;
    this.updateUserModel.socialMedia = this.profileForm.value.firstName;
    this.updateUserModel.state = this.profileForm.value.state;
    this.updateUserModel.dob = this.profileForm.value.DOB;
    this.updateUserModel.city = this.profileForm.value.city;
    //Spouse Details
    this.updateUserModel.spouseDetails = this.spouseDetails;
    this.updateUserModel.photoData=this.selectedFile;
    this.updateUserModel.childrensDetails =  this.profileForm.value.childrensDetails;
  }
```

Angular Model

```
    export class UserDetailModel {
    childrensDetails: ChildrensDetailsModel[]=[];
    spouseDetails!: SpouseDetails
    id:string="";
    photoData!:File;
    photo!:FormData
}
```

This is the Controller

```
 [HttpPost]
    [Route("UpdateUser")]
    public async Task<JsonResult> UpdateUser([FromBody] FileModel userDetailModel)
    {
        var userslist = await _userBusiness.UpdateUser(userDetailModel);
        return new JsonResult(new { userslist });
    }
```

Service file in angular

```
  updateUser(userDetailModel:any):Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<any>(`${UserProfileURLConstants.USER_PROFILE}`,userDetailModel);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To post file with other additional data from angular frontend to API backend, as you mentioned, we can create and populate data with `FormData`, and make backend action method get values from posted form fields by specifying `[FromForm]` attribute.

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('Photo', selectedFile);
formData.append('SpouseDetails.SpouseEmail', 'test@example.com');
formData.append('SpouseDetails.SpouseCity', 'blabla..');
// console.log(formData);
this.http
  .post<any>('{url_here}', formData)
  .subscribe((data) => {
    //...
```

[image]

Besides, if you'd like to post photo file(s) with data in request body, you can try to use [`FileReader.readAsDataURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL) to get base64-encoded string, then you can convert it into a byte array in action method on backend.